# Beginner AngularJS can't get model and controller to connect

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.  The following code controller is not connecting to the model.  I just get

I am {{1+4}}

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>AngularJS Email App</title>
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.js"></script>
        I am {{1+4}}

        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: You should write `I am {{1+4}}` in the body, not in the script.

Comment: The last `</script>` doesn't close anything, remove it

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül, good catch, @pob, just remove `</script>` at last

Comment: remove app name <html ng-app="myApp">, just mention as ng-app without any value i.e. <html ng-app>. When you mention module name then it must be defined and declared.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your controllers, directives, etc. in your script. The content of website like `I am {{1+4}}` should be in the view, i.e. body part of your code outside of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="begin">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('begin',[]);
        app.controller('BusContorller', function($scope){
      
        });

  </script>

 
    <div ng-controller="BusContorller as bus">
        I am: {{1+4}}
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linking ng-app to myApp, you haven't created that module yet so it won't work. If you check your developer tools you will see an error. The reason your getting an error is because AngularJS is not being bootstrapped to the view since it can't find the myApp module.

You have two options:

1. Remove the myApp and just do ng-app= ""
   This will work since angular won't look for a specific module to bootstrap.
2. You can create the module by adding another script tag with the following code.

   ```
   var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
   ```